# Unusual large table size in one data warehouse while with the same table, its size is significantly smaller in another data warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Currently, we have a strange issue in our data warehouse (Azure Synapse Analytics) as 1 table in production instance has 52 GB in size with 18 million records. I copied that table to our development instance (I exported the mentioned table to csv file in ADLS GEN2 and copy it into our development data warehouse using ADF)  to check why this table has large size and causing store procedures to run slow.

Strangely, the table size is just 17 GB while the tables between the two instances are the same in row count, contents and DDL. The two Data warehouses have the same DWU and other specifications. As I do not have much permission to research on production instance and I can not replicate the same table size on development instance.

Can someone help me to troubleshoot this issue or guide me in the right direction to rectify this ?

Kind regards,

Ken

Comment: I suppose a couple of things to try might be to recreate the table using CTAS and ensure the user recreating it as a large or xlarge resource class, and you're running at a decent DWU (ie *not* 100).  You are also sure they have the same distribution and indexing?  eg if the bigger table is `HEAP` rather than `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX` that would explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck the process that you have followed for this and if it results same you can contact MS support team.

But before that I would suggest you try to copy the table **directly from one synapse to another using the Copy activity** in ADF and check the size of the table.

Please refer this [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory) for that.